# AutoCompleteTextView does not work in ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

My `autoCategory_book` variable does not work from a `ViewHolder`.

The errors are:

- error: cannot find symbol method `getResources()`

```
Category_book = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_book);
```

- error: cannot infer type arguments for `ArrayAdapter<>`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Category_book);
```

- Code

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            AutoCompleteTextView autoCategory_book;
            String[] Category_book;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                autoCategory_book = itemView.findViewById(R.id.autoCategory_book);
                Category_book = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_book);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Category_book);
                autoCategory_book.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this for fix it:

```
Category_book = itemView.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_book);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(itemView.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Category_book);
```

The ArrayAdapter constructor required a context, and you pass a reference for the view holder. And for access to the android resource you need a context too.

Comment: I'm very happy to be able to help ;)